# Set variable in ajax success and use outside of request

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, variables

I have my ajax call like this and I want to set a variable globally so I can use it letter My code is below Please give suggestions for accessing UserTr variable:-

```
    var UserTr;
    $.ajax({
            url:'ReAjaxFunction.php',
            data:'fun=3',
            type:'POST',
            cache:false,
            success:function(UserResponse){
              var FetchAppUser= JSON.parse(UserResponse);
              $.each(FetchAppUser.AppUser,function(key,value){
                UserTr ='<tr><td colspan="2">Approval Status</td></tr><tr><td>'+value.Name+'</td><td>'+value.ApprovalStatus+'</td></tr>'
              });
            }
          });
    alert(UserTr);
```

Comment: since ajax is asynchronous, alert will give u undefined. I mean alert will execute before response from ajax comes.So try to put alert inside ajax success call.

Comment: with async calls you can never really know when it returned. So the best place to use the results of their calls is in the callback, i.e. in the success function

Comment: Thank you vary much

Answer (score 0):

Your `alert` at the end is being invoked its just the Ajax call is asynchronous so the alert is running before the Ajax call completes.

At the time of the alert your variable `UserTr` is un-defined so your alert is empty.

However, if you were to move your `alert` call to the inside of the Ajax call right after you actually set the `UserTr` variable then it would be defined and have a value (assuming the JSON parse succeeds and the expected structure is present.

That being said, the way you set `UserTr` inside of the Ajax call means that on each loop iteration of `$.each` it is being over-written -- I think you want to use `UserTr +=` to accumulate a series of table rows.

To do that you'd also want to initialize your variable to a string.

So do this:

`var UserTr = "";`

Then replace `UserTr = ...` with `UserTr += ...`

After your iteration then you can do something with the fully populated `UserTr`

Comment: I understand But still I am not able to populate result of UserTr after the ajax. I just want to use this variable globlly

Comment: What do you mean by globally? If you assign it to the `window` object (e.g. `window.UserTr = 2` then its basically as global as you can get

Comment: Found the solution